# What does `&ClassName::function` method of calling represent?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

`connect( &objTwo, &Two::emitThisSignal, this, &Controller::mySlot );`

Here Two is a separate class. Its object has been created in Controller class. Its signal has to be connected to Controller class's slot.

Signature of connect is:

```
connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal, const QObject *receiver, const char *method, Qt::ConnectionType type)
connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal, const char *method, Qt::ConnectionType type) const
connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject *receiver, PointerToMemberFunction method, Qt::ConnectionType type)
connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, Functor functor)
connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject *context, Functor functor, Qt::ConnectionType type)
```

Which signature out of above does my connect call represent?

Why can't I simply write: `connect( &objTwo, objTwo.emitThisSignal, this, this->mySlot );`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which signature out of above does my connect call represent?

This one:

```
connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, 
       const QObject *receiver, PointerToMemberFunction method, Qt::ConnectionType type)
```

The last argument is default(`Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection`), so you don't have explicitly specify it. [Link to docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-3)

> Why can't I simply write: `connect( &objTwo, objTwo.emitThisSignal, this, this->mySlot );?`

Because that is invalid C++ syntax if you want to pass a pointer to member function. `objTwo.emitThisSignal` in C++ syntax would mean, access the *data* member `emitThisSignal` inside `objTwo`, while the function expects a pointer to member function.

---

However if you write:

```
connect( &objTwo, SIGNAL(objTwo.emitThisSignal), this, SLOT(this->mySlot) );
```

Your code will probably compile but would not work as intended. The reason for this can be understood by look at the first `connect` signature:

```
connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal, 
        const QObject *receiver, const char *method, Qt::ConnectionType type)
```

It takes pointer to `char*` as 2nd and 4th arguments. So any syntax would get compiled. The macros `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` convert these into strings and then Qt uses these at runtime to call the right slot(s) when a signal is emitted. The above syntax will likely not even result in a crash or any warnings even. I know this sounds apalling, but such was the state of Qt before Qt 5 came.

These days it is highly recommended that you use these three signatures:

```
connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject *receiver, PointerToMemberFunction method, Qt::ConnectionType type)
connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, Functor functor)
connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject *context, Functor functor, Qt::ConnectionType type)
```